# DKIM with Exim4 on Debian "Buster"

Tags: debian, exim, dkim

Can anybody confirm please that in order to get DKIM working the exim4-lite package still has to be replaced with exim4-heavy?

If so, what is the correct sequence? Something like

```
apt-get purge exim4-daemon-light
apt-get install exim4-daemon-heavy
```

followed by MTA and DKIM configuration?

For completeness (and for anybody getting here via Google) this is for Debian "Buster", packaging might obviously change in future releases.

Comment: Instead of `purge`, use `apt-get remove`, so you can at least keep your existing config in place. Then add the DKIM configuration.

Comment: I think you're saying I'm correct... please add that as an answer so that I can accept it.